# Click play button on Flash Object with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, flash, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have to click on play button of Flash object swf, like this

[image]

this is its html:

```
<object id="flashObject" width="100%" height="26px" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" name="flashObject" data="audioplayer.swf">
```

I am stuck here, don't know how to click on play button. I tried with click with id, but it didn't work, apparently. Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the position (x, y) of the play button in your element. Identify the position and then use these lines of code :

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);   
builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("flashObject")), poxXPlay, posYPlay).click().build().perform();
```

This should do the work.